# SQL Server - How to get user login mappings?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know this question has been asked before in many forms, but unfortunately, none of them helped me in this quite basic need - I'm looking for a script which takes as a parameters a particular login's name & database and return the appropriated associated roles.

For example - for the attached screen shot, when passing the script the *ADMA1* user name & the *fogbugzRelease* database the output shoul be `db_owner`.

[image]

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81595/a-query-that-lists-all-mapped-users-for-a-given-login check it

Comment: Not what I need...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below query to get database role assigned to the user

```
DECLARE @command nvarchar(4000) 
DECLARE @DBRole TABLE (DBName sysname, UserName sysname, RoleName varchar(255))
SELECT @command = 'use [?]
SELECT ''?'' AS DB_Name,
case prin.name when ''dbo'' then (select SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) from master.sys.databases where name =''?'') else prin.name end AS UserName
,isnull(USER_NAME(mem.role_principal_id),'''') AS AssociatedRole
FROM sys.database_principals prin
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_role_members mem ON prin.principal_id=mem.member_principal_id'

INSERT INTO @DBRole
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command 

SELECT * FROM @DBRole t 
WHERE t.UserName like '%YourUserName%'
and t.DBName like '%Your DB Name%'
```

Comment: The 1st query works well, but won't work when running it on administrator user that has a sys.admin privileges. The query just won't return anything although the does have assigned roles.

Comment: @Nimrod, Thanks for bringing it to my attention.  Modified the answer to get all the roles even if the user is DB Owner

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query and in the commented section provide database and username as per your requirement and uncomment the lines. Hope it helps.

```
DECLARE @DB_USers TABLE
(DBName sysname, UserName sysname, LoginType sysname, AssociatedRole varchar(max),create_date datetime,modify_date datetime)

INSERT @DB_USers
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
'
use [?]
SELECT ''?'' AS DB_Name,
case prin.name when ''dbo'' then prin.name + '' (''+ (select SUSER_SNAME(owner_sid) from master.sys.databases where name =''?'') + '')'' else prin.name end AS UserName,
prin.type_desc AS LoginType,
isnull(USER_NAME(mem.role_principal_id),'''') AS AssociatedRole ,create_date,modify_date
FROM sys.database_principals prin
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_role_members mem ON prin.principal_id=mem.member_principal_id
WHERE prin.sid IS NOT NULL and prin.sid NOT IN (0x00) and
prin.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND prin.name NOT LIKE ''##%'''
SELECT
dbname,username ,logintype ,create_date ,modify_date ,
STUFF(
(
SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(500),associatedrole)
FROM @DB_USers user2
WHERE
user1.DBName=user2.DBName AND user1.UserName=user2.UserName
FOR XML PATH('')
)
,1,1,'') AS Permissions_user
FROM @DB_USers user1
--where dbname ='master' and username = 'public'
GROUP BY dbname,username ,logintype ,create_date ,modify_date
ORDER BY DBName,username
```